# rabbitmq set message Properties php

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq, amqp

I'm trying to set a message property using the [RabbitMQ Bundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle) in Symfony but I don't see where/how I can do this. Here is how I do it in the RabbitMQ Admin UI

[image]

The Properties expiration: 50000 is what I would like to set.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

Since Jan 8, 2014, you cat set message properties using [RabbitMQ Bundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle), you can review the commit [here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle/commit/2f7b50775d2b6712f3abfc1333e202cb4e812e75)

Now, when you publish a message you cat set the array $additionalProperties

```
public function publish($msgBody, $routingKey = '', $additionalProperties = array())
```

You can find the supported message properties [here](https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/doc/AMQPMessage.md)

For example:

```
$msg = ['arg1' => 'val1'];
$queue->setContentType('application/json');
$queue->publish(
        json_encode($msg),
        "",
        ['expiration' => '50000']
);
```

If you want to use "headers" for custom headers, it is a bit more complicated because you have to define the datatype for each value. To send, e.g. $headers['arg1'] = "val1" like a string, you have to do something like that:

```
$msg = ['arg1' => 'val1'];
$queue->setContentType('application/json');
$queue->publish(
        json_encode($msg),
        "",
        ["application_headers" => ["arg1" => ["S", "val1"]]]
);
```

Valid datatypes are:

S - String

I - Integer

D - Decimal

T - Timestamps

F - Table

A - Array

Answer (score 0):

That's not doable at the moment. You can set message properties if you use the underlying php-amqplib library that the bundle depends on

Comment: Is there any other documentation on this as I don't see it here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.amqp.php

Comment: I think I found it: https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib/blob/master/doc/AMQPMessage.md